# Is there an international standard on the frequencies used by car toll tags?

Tags: rf, frequency, wifi, standard

We're finding that when we drive through a car-toll collection point, our Car-Pay Wifi connection cuts out. (Music and maps cut out).

I'm guessing that the Car-toll tag system uses the same frequencies used by Wifi.

My question is: **Is there an international standard on the frequencies used by car toll tags?**

EDIT:

- By 'wifi' I mean 'router wifi' eg 802.11b/g/n
- The toll tag system is in an isolated plastic case, connected to nothing.

Comment: Is that "marketing term wifi" (meaning actually a cellular data connection) or *actual* wifi as the wireless standard used by your laptop to talk to your router? (by the way, I find interference to be a very unlikely reason)

Comment: Wireless router wifi

Answer (score -1):

> Is there an international standard on the frequencies used by car toll tags?

That doesn't matter to your use case, your question is whether *your* standard interferes with your wifi, and I don't know the standard your car-tool collection points use. Neverless, yes, there are standards. Multiple standards[.](https://xkcd.com/927/)

> I'm guessing that the Car-toll tag system uses the same frequencies used by Wifi.

Generally, systems operating in unlicensed / ISM bands are required to operate in a manner that avoids harmful interference with other system. I'd be greatly surprised if that wasn't the case for toll collection systems.

Even if they were operating on the same frequencies, that would pose no problem: the amount of data exchanged with the toll station would be very small, the communication hence very short, and since Wifi is a collision-detect and collision-avoidance system anyway, not any special in any way then say, you carrying a smart phone that actively pings previously seen SSIDs, or you bringing a bluetooth device, or a lot of other things.

So, I don't think "interference with commercial infrastructure" to be a likely reason. Also, why would your maps drop out? That kind of software is designed to work without connectivity for seconds to minutes, not for the milliseconds that your car and a toll system would be interacting. Same for music playback: your media player prefetches whole songs as quickly as possible, usually. I've never seen an audio player with less than half a second of raw audio buffer when streaming from anywhere. A data connection not being flawless all the time is normal, even for wired internet (Ethernet, DSL, cable, fiber...).

Probably, it's just software quality. Your car's wifi/entertainment system is running on shared resources as the toll collection system, maybe; maybe it's just "confused" by some broadcast messages sent over the car's internal communication buses.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. The toll collection device is in an isolated plastic case, connected to nothing.

Comment: @hawkeye then you either have spurious problems with your board electronics, or the toll bridge does something illegal.